# Create Multiple lists from a single list

Tags: python, encryption

so I'm trying to create a hill cipher in python, and am not sure how to break up the input into multiple lists that each have 2 characters in them right now.

What I have right now is

```
mess = input('What is the message: ').upper()
m = [mess[i: i + 2] for i in range(0, len(mess), 2)]
```

which will output each pair of characters, but will only do it into one list

```
['CI', 'PH', 'ER']
```

I want to break them up to start with for multiplying by the encryption matrix, but haven't been able to do so yet and I'm not sure how to make this into a matrix numpy could handle as a 2 x *n*.

Comment: Can you please post a desired `input-output` pair?

Comment: `What is the message: Cipher

    ['CI', 'PH', 'ER']`

Comment: I guess that if the input is Cipher. He wants the output to be [CI], [PH], [ER]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work now:

New Edit:

```
words = input()
the_words = words.split()

new_list = []
for i in the_words:
    for b in range(0, len(i), 2):
        if b+1 < len(i)-1:
             new_list.append([i[b], i[b+1]])


print(new_list)
```

Comment: That's closer, but the problem is that it will print the same letter twice `[['C', 'I'], ['I', 'P'], ['P', 'H'], ['H', 'E']]`

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping for, thank you. Would it be possible if you could then break up the new_list into separate lists, or if that isn't possible.

Comment: You are welcome. Right now, new_list stores the grouped letters as lists, so thus the entire list is a list of lists. If you want to separate the lists within the list, you can loop over the list, access the first element of the resulting list, and then do something with that, such as assign it to a string or dictionary key or value.

Comment: Is it possible to change the code to be able to take the user input for a word, then break it up into the lists?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use brackets to to generate a nested list

```
[[m[i:i+2]] for i in range(0, len(m), 2)]
```

Output:

```
[['CI'], ['PH'], ['ER']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you want:

```
result = [''.join(item) for item in zip(a[::2], a[1::2])]
```

Or to get 3 lists:

```
a = 'CIPHER'
m = [[''.join(item)] for item in zip(a[::2], a[1::2])]
print(m)
```

**EXTRA**

Assigning sub lists to variables:

```
for i, item in enumerate(m):
    globals()['v{}'.format(i)] = item

print(v0)
print(v1)
print(v2)
```

Comment: No, the output for that is `['CIPH']`, when the output I was going for was `['CI'],['PH'],['ER']`

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: The input was just CIPHER as a single string, which I then want to change into 3 lists that are `['CI'],['PH'],['ER']`

Comment: Thank you for that, the edit works great. Follow up question, could you use split to then break m up from a list with the lists in it, could you have multiple variables to then store each list?

Comment: Hope this answers your question. Not sure why you didn't accept/upvote my solution as I answered first :(

Comment: Sorry, the other answer worked better, as I was looking for then the lists in each one to be broken up, so the output would be `[C','I'],['P','H'],['E','R']`, your edit works well, but how could you change it to work with user input, that could be any length?

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = [mess[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(mess), 2)]
```

Comment: That gives the same output as a the original, which only prints as a single list.